# Interval of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\cdot\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}2\right)$

Tags: limits, power-series

What is the interval of convergence of this power series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\cdot\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}2\right)$$

There's no limit to $$\frac{\sin\left((n+1)\cdot\frac\pi2 \right)}{ \sin\left(n\cdot\left(\frac\pi 2\right)\right)}$$

Comment: The denominator is $0$ when $n$ is even.

Comment: What is $\sin \frac {n\pi}2$, $n=1,2,3,\ldots$

Comment: Before using Ratio test note that $\sin (n\pi/2)=0$ for $n$ even and $(-1)^{(n-1)/2}$ for $n$ odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that:
$$\left|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n \sin \left(\frac{n\pi}{2} \right) \right| \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |x|^n \cdot \left|\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2} \right)\right| \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |x|^n$$

The right-hand side is the geometric series and that has radius of convergence $1$. So, your series has radius of convergence at least $1$. Your series will not converge at the endpoints $1$ and $-1$ because the limit of the terms, at those points, does not go to $0$. It follows that it has radius of convergence $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} |\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})|^\frac{1}{n}=1$$
by Cauchy-Hadamard's theorem we get that the radius of convergence is $1$.

If $x=\pm 1$ the power series does not converge, as $\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})x^n$ does not go to $0$.

**Remark**: As observed in another answer, you do not actually need Cauchy-Hadamard's criterion in this particular case. By the way, this is a general method.